# Method gets call on onBackPress in android

Tags: android, android-activity, baseadapter

I am working on Base adapter in Android and i want to know that which overriden method gets call in BaseAdapter Class if i press onBackPress in some activity. Please help me, I have searched and didnt find any solution.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have listview and you have a custom adapter set for the listview. Listview is in your activity.

```
class MyActivity extends Activity
{
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstancestate)
   {
          setContentView(R.layout.main);
          ListView lv= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
          CustomAdapter cus= new CustomAdapter(MyActivity.this);
          lv.setAdapter(cus);   
   }
 }
 class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter
 {
    ....................
 }
```

**So when you press back button the current activity is popped form the back stack, destroyed and previous activity in the back stack takes focus.This the default behaviour.**

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html

**You can override onKeyDown(params) in your activity**

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
    onBackPressed();

}

return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

public void onBackPressed() {
   //do something
finish();
return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Overide [onBackPressed](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed%28%29) in your activity and Change data to adapter accordingly then call [notifyDataSetChanged](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29)

Answer (score 0):

The onBackPressed will be activated in your Activity class. It is not an event of BaseAdapter class. So override your onBackPressed method in the Activity class.

Answer (score 0):

you can pass activity `reference` to adapter via `constructor` like:

```
CustomAdapter customAdapter=CustomAdapter(getApplicationContext(),arrayList,HomeActivity.this);
```

and in Your Custom Adapter

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
Context context;
ArrayList<CategoryModel> arrCategoryModel;
AppCompatActivity activity;
public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<CategoryModel> arrCategoryModel, AppCompatActivity activity)
{
    this.context=context;
    this.arrCategoryModel=arrCategoryModel;
    this.activity=activity;
} }
```

Now you can call `activity.onBackPressed();` wherever you want.